# Possible to downgrade/rollback .NET 4.5 runtime?

Tags: asp.net, clr, rollback, asp.net-4.5, downgrade

I was wondering if there was a way to rollback or downgrade the .NET 4.5 runtime back to .NET 4.0.  I am not talking about rolling back projects that are targetting 4.5 and bringing them back to 4.0, I am wondering if I upgrade the .NET framework to 4.5 of the runtime, is there a way to go back?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good attempt to explain it [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx) by Hanselman. However, I believe it is still confusing.

The way I understand is that if you want to go back, you will need to uninstall 4.5 and 4.0 and re-install 4.0.

Comment: I've read that before but I didn't quite see how it addresses my issue.  Your awesome seems to address it though, if that is a correct solution, heh.

Comment: @brian: the article says that 4.5 is an in-place upgrade to 4.0; so the implication is that you need to re-install 4.0 if you want a clean rollback.